Reactor Netty: Connection prematurely closed BEFORE response with WebClient
When trying to process data retrieved from the WebClient at a random point in time I get the "Connection prematurely closed BEFORE response" error. The pages contain quite a lot of data that is processed afterwards (mostly DB updates and inserts). After a random amount of time, I get the error:
**Reactor Netty: Connection prematurely closed BEFORE response with WebClient.**
The method in question is the following:
  private Mono<String> migrateSomeData() {
    return getAllPages()
        .flatMapIterable(Page::getItems)
        .filter(this::isValidItem)
        .doOnNext(item -> doSomeLogging())
        .filter(item-> this.checkIfAlreadyProcessed(item))
        .flatMap(this::mapToDto)
        .flatMap(this::persist)
        .doOnNext(this::saveAsProcessed)
        .collectList()
        .map(this::getTotalAmountOfProcessed);
  }

The code has had certain parts omitted for brewity. getAllPages utilizes the Flux .expand method to recursively call the next pages. This is verified and works correctly. One more important thing to note is that all database operations are blocking as we have not implemented reactive jdbc.
I've tried updating the webclient configuration:
@Bean
  public WebClient someClient(
      ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager clientAuthorizedClientManager) {

    ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction oauth =
        new ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(clientAuthorizedClientManager);
    oauth.setDefaultClientRegistrationId("clientId");

    final int size = 16 * 1024 * 1024;
    final ExchangeStrategies strategies = buildClientWithExtendedResponseSize(size);

    return WebClient.builder()
        .defaultHeader("Accept", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
        .defaultHeader("subscription-key", someKeyValue)
        .clientConnector(createWiretappedClientHttpConnector(this.getClass()))
        .filter(oauth)
        .exchangeStrategies(strategies)
        .build();
  }

  private static ExchangeStrategies buildClientWithExtendedResponseSize(int size) {
    return ExchangeStrategies.builder()
        .codecs(codecs -> codecs.defaultCodecs().maxInMemorySize(size))
        .build();
  }

private ClientHttpConnector createWiretappedClientHttpConnector(Class<?> invokedClass) {
    HttpClient httpClient =
        HttpClient.create()
            .option(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true)
            .responseTimeout(Duration.ofMinutes(5))
            .doOnConnected(
                conn ->
                    conn.addHandlerLast(new ReadTimeoutHandler(5 * 60))
                        .addHandlerLast(new WriteTimeoutHandler(5 * 60)))
            .compress(true)
            .wiretap(
                invokedClass.getCanonicalName(), LogLevel.TRACE, AdvancedByteBufFormat.TEXTUAL);
    return new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient);
  }

I've also tried to narrow this code down as much as possible so forgive me for any structural mistakes.
I've tested this against a local mocked instance of the API in wiremock and the issue still persists so that should rule out server configuration issues.
Can it be possible that my processing code is too slow and that the WebClients returned response is not consumed in time and the webclient decides to close the connection?

Sorry for the late reply.
There is an issue about it raised on reactor's github page.
This issue seems to be something like "the client sends [ACK] and no [ACK,FIN] and keeps the connection opened. So, the connection is not closed by the client and later is reused, resulting in this error".
The solution should be setting a max-idle-time (The maximum time that this connection stays idle in the connection pool). The value suggested is what has the client server as keepAliveTimeout, but if this is confusing, try something small and play around. So the solution should look like this:
ConnectionProvider connectionProviderWithMaxIdleTime = ConnectionProvider.builder("withMaxIdleTime")
                .maxIdleTime(Duration.ofSeconds(120)) //if issue persists reduce this
                .build();
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.create(connectionProviderWithMaxIdleTime)
                .option(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true)
                {...the rest of your code...}

Hope this helps!

This seems to have worked! I had to put a value of 15 second for the idle time though. This seems to have fixed it but I will need a few days to verify the behavior. Is a value this low normal?

I guess it has to do with your use case. My understanding is that if a client establishes a connection with the server, makes a request, the last signal is not FIN, so the connection remains open for more requests from the same client, until the idle-time setting is meet (or the keepAlive value from server). So if you expect more requests from this client to the same server, maybe you want a higher value for example. To avoid the cost of reconnecting to the server. If this client only makes 1 request then you can go low. In such changes though, i would always run my performance tests too...

After you verify the behavior, please let us know in the comments, for documentation purposes. And if it is the solution you were looking for, please mark it as resolved, again for future references! thanks

The client does communicate with the same server many times as It is a paginated response and I process all of the data available. But this value seems to work and the performance did not take a hit as far as I can see. No errors of this today, so thats great, was having quite some trouble with this one.

You may want to check also https://projectreactor.io/docs/netty/release/reference/index.html#faq.connection-closed

@stelios.anastasakis After 5 days of the data processing working fine, this morning I encountered the error once again. This definitely reduced the number of times the error happens but doesn't seem to be completely fixed.

maybe you need to tune a bit more? Like play with the value you use.
Also, try debugging using the guides @VioletaGeorgieva shared. There might be other areas that caused this one failure, like some target server configuration. If it is 1 error after many days, it is probably something very small and specific

@stelios.anastasakis I've requested that the tools such as tcpdump be installed on the remote machine in order to debug the issue. It seems very specific indeed as the issue hasn't happened since the last time I commented here. This is still good enough for the current use case and I will see what happens further when I am able to debug it. Will update the post with additional information once I have it since it might be of relevance to whoever else experiences the issue.

I have encounter the similiar problem.
According to the previous answer by stelios.anastasakis, I reduced the frequency of the problem by using maxIdleTime, although it still happened occasionally.
Now I use evictInBackground with maxIdleTime. So far the result is encouraging: In a whole day test, the problem has not recurred.
            WebClient.Builder builder = WebClient.builder();

        ConnectionProvider connectionProviderWithMaxIdleTime = ConnectionProvider.builder("withMaxIdleTime")
                .maxIdleTime(Duration.ofSeconds(20)) //if issue persists reduce this
                .evictInBackground(Duration.ofSeconds(19))
                .build();

        // 设置最大缓冲字节数
        builder.clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(
                HttpClient.create(connectionProviderWithMaxIdleTime)
                        .option(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true)
                        .option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, 65000)   // to fix connection timed out after 30000 ms ?
                        .responseTimeout(Duration.ofMinutes(5))
                        .wiretap(true)
                        .doOnConnected(conn -> conn.addHandlerLast(new ReadTimeoutHandler(5 * 60))
                                .addHandlerLast(new WriteTimeoutHandler(5 * 60)))
                        .doOnDisconnected(conn -> log.info("WebClient Disconnected {} localAddress {}", webClient, conn.channel().localAddress()))
                        .compress(true)
        ));
        builder.codecs(clientCodecConfigurer -> clientCodecConfigurer.defaultCodecs().maxInMemorySize(20 * 1024 * 1024));  //20MB

        return builder.build();

Two lines of code above related to this question are:
.maxIdleTime(Duration.ofSeconds(20)) //if issue persists reduce this
.evictInBackground(Duration.ofSeconds(19))

Referring to https://projectreactor.io/docs/netty/release/reference/index.html#connection-pool-timeout ,  evictInBackground means:
When this option is enabled, each connection pool regularly checks for connections that are eligible for removal according to eviction criteria like maxIdleTime. By default, this background eviction is disabled.
I think you can also try it.

Interesting. I will give it a try. The issue does resurface occasionally for me as well.

I've tried the solution and it does indeed seem to help. One very important thing to note is that this adds quite a lot of overhead in terms of cpu utility. I've had problems with my docker container reaching 90% - 100% cpu utility and not going down at all. This can also probably be fixed by explicitly disposing of these connectionProviders, but definitely something to keep in mind.
